# How to create output files with different names using Shell?

Tags: linux, bash, slurm

I have a R script (`abc.R`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

print("HELLO")
```

And a batch script containing the R script (`example.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
module load Rstats
module load RstatsPackages


Rscript /home1/R_scripts/abc.R   > "result.txt"
```

And another batch script (`multiple.sh`), which calls the above script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for((i=1;i<=10;i++))
do

     sbatch -p normal -t 4:00:00 -N 1 -n 4 example.sh $i

done

sh multiple.sh
```

This script calls the above script ten times that way my Rscript will be run 10 times. It is running 10 times, but it is generating only one result.txt. However, I want multiple result files like `result1.txt`, `result2.txt`, `result3.txt` and so on.

Comment: Why the `slurm` tag?

Comment: I though that way someone familiar with batch (often slurm users) would help me out. But i got the problem resolved. I can remove the tag. Thanks

Comment: @vmaroli suggestion worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the iteration number (`$i`) is passed as an argument to `example.sh` from `multiple.sh`, same can be used to create a file per iteration. To do so change last line of `example.sh` to:

```
Rscript /home1/R_scripts/abc.R   > "result${1}.txt"
```